# Only Showing one person for a specific role, discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I'm having trouble listing everyone in the discord server that has a certain role.
Even if there are multiple people with the same role, it only lists one of them, regardless of how many are in the same channel.

I'm pretty new to discord.js and I'm having trouble understanding the docs

```
var CSCid = "496507412300300288";

var CSCmembers = interaction.guild.roles.cache.get(CSCid).members.map(m=>m.user.tag);

console.log(CSCmembers)
```

The output only shows one person out of many who have the role.

Comment: Have you tried fetching all the members. It's possible it's only returning the cached members

Comment: how exactly would you do that and what is the difference between cached members and all the members,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try fetching all of the GuildMembers first. A cached element is an object that it's saved in memory and can be easily accessed (By using `.get()`). An *uncached* element is an element that isnt stored in memory and requires an API call to Discord in order to retrieve and *then* cache it (By using `.fetch()`)

```js
var CSCid = "496507412300300288";

interaction.guild.members.fetch().then(members => {
   var CSCmembers = interaction.guild.roles.cache
      .get(CSCid).members
      .map(m=>m.user.tag)
      .join(', ');

   console.log(CSCmembers);
});
```

Ensure you have the Guild Member's Intent enabled